# Fitting sklearn's SVM classifier with data from a pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, scikit-learn

I'm trying to use SVM but I dont know how to fit the model when I am using pandas data frame. If my data looks like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"x": ['011', '100', '111'] , "y": [0,1,0]})
df.x.apply(lambda x: np.array(list(map(int,x))))
>>>df
    x           y
0   [0, 1, 1]   0
1   [1, 0, 0]   1
2   [1, 1, 1]   0
```

If I try to fit the model this way:

```
clf = svm.SVC().fit(df.x, df.y)
```

I am getting this error:

```
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

What is the correct way to fit the SVM using this data frame?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"x": ['011', '100', '111'] , "y": [0,1,0]})
df.x = df.x.apply(lambda x: list(map(int,x)))

df
           x  y
0  [0, 1, 1]  0
1  [1, 0, 0]  1
2  [1, 1, 1]  0
```

---

`df.x` is a column of arrays. This probably isn't the best way to store data, and it would seem `sklearn` isn't very good at understanding it. It would be simpler to convert everything to a list of lists and pass *that* to `SVC`. Try this:

```
x = df.x.tolist()
print(x)
[[0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1]]
SVC().fit(x, df.y)
```

Comment: It worked thanks so much, but can we use numpy array instead of list of list. Because when we have a large dataset numpy array is much faster than list of list?

Comment: @Ali  sklearn is wonderful. Passing a list or a numpy array to sklearn makes no difference.

Comment: @Ali `SVC` is going to turn it into an array for you.  However, you can make your process more efficient by not storing your input array in that fashion.

Comment: @piRSquared let say x is the pixel of an image and y is the class, what's the better way to store this kind of data than the way I did above?

Comment: @Ali Separate columns for each bit?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ actually I try to do that but I couldn't figure it out, my csv file looks like this `1010101011     1` first column is the image bits and the second column is the label. Do you know how I can do it?

Comment: @Ali I'd recommend doing a little research on how to get your data to look as you want. If that doesn't work, you should open another question.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ *"Passing a list or a numpy array to sklearn makes no difference"* actually it does: `list` works whereas `np.array` doesn't, in this case.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution is the code below.

```python
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

from sklearn.svm import SVC

df = pd.DataFrame({"x": ['011', '100', '111'] , "y": [0,1,0]})
x = df.x.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(list(x)))
x
# Out[2]:
#    0  1  2
# 0  0  1  1
# 1  1  0  0
# 2  1  1  1

SVC().fit(x, df.y)
# Out[3]:
# SVC(C=1.0, cache_size=200, class_weight=None, coef0=0.0,
#   decision_function_shape=None, degree=3, gamma='auto', kernel='rbf',
#   max_iter=-1, probability=False, random_state=None, shrinking=True,
#   tol=0.001, verbose=False)
```

Comment: Yes, this is another alternative I mentioned in the comments, but neglected to address as an answer. +1

Answer (score 0):

```py
import numpy as np
from sklearn.svm import SVC

# Convert your data frame's columns into arrays
features = df['x'].to_numpy()
labels = df['y'].to_numpy()

# feed into your classifier 
SVC().fit(features,labels)
```

Comment: Try to explain the user what is the issue in his code and why your solution would solve it.